# min_by Ruby (smallest value in associative array)

Tags: ruby

I have the following  in a model class `User`:

```
  def thisUsersUserRole
    userRoles = []
    self.userRoles.each do |ur|
      userRoles << { "id" => ur.role_id, "name" => ur.roleName }
    end
    #line in question
    userRoles.values.min_by(&:first)
    # puts userRoles
  end
```

The `puts` shows the following:

```
{"id"=>1, "name"=>"admin"}
{"id"=>2, "name"=>"owner"}
{"id"=>3, "name"=>"manager"}
```

I am trying to search the array (no more than 10 total, but from my research this is the least expensive method) and return the `"name"` attribute value of the lowest `"id"` value in the hash/associative array.

How do I use the `min_by` to accomplish this.   The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) isn't making any sense...  Please help me understand the syntax as well, as just providing me the correct line won't help me learn.

Comment: Your code cannot be interpreted. `userRoles` is an `Array` and `Array` does not have a method `#values`.

Comment: that is my attempt, I dont know how to correct it.  @xdazz s answer doesnt work either , I get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'role_id' for {"id"=>1, "name"=>"admin"}:Hash`, and since there is no clearer explanation about the method, I cannot fix it myself.

Comment: I find using a local variable with the same name as a persistent attribute very confusing.also, you already have a collection of objects, why put them into an array before finding the minimum? The answer provided who uses the persisted collection, not your unnecessary array.

Comment: You claim that the documentation does not make any sense, but your question does not make any sense either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the existing code and your response to my comment, I think this is what you want:

```
role_hash_with_smallest_id = userRoles.min_by {|role_hash| role_hash['id']}
role_hash_with_smallest_id['name']
```

However, there is probably a much simpler way:

```
role_with_smallest_id = self.userRoles.min_by {|role| role.id}
role_with_smallest_id.name
```

which can be abbreviated as

```
role_with_smallest_id = self.userRoles.min_by(&:id)
role_with_smallest_id.name
```

This is assuming `self.userRoles` already is an `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

Try below:

```
def thisUsersUserRole
  userRoles.min_by(&:role_id).roleName
end
```

Edit:
If `userRoles` is an array of hash, then try:

```
def thisUsersUserRole
  userRoles.min_by{ |ur| ur['id'] }['roleName']
end
```

Comment: I get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'role_id' for {"id"=>1, "name"=>"admin"}:Hash`, and since there is no clearer explanation about the method, I cannot fix it myself.

Comment: @chrisFrisina You need to give what is `userRoles` first, by your code posted, there should by a method `role_id`, but from you comment, it becomes an array of hash.